# Insert a next line between each designated delimiters in Python

Tags: python-3.x

Given that the number of columns is 3, and the head of the data is correct, the column delimiter is by "<|>", the mismatched lines are due to accidental feed by a new line.

Consider the following CSV file,

```
    PERSON_ID<|>DEPT_ID<|>DATE_JOINED
    AAAAA<|>S1<|>2021/01
/03
    BBBBBB<|>S2<|>2021/02/03
    CCCCC<|>S1<|>2021/03/05
```

I wish the output like,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahZPJ.png)

The first thing I did is to remove the white spacing in the CSV file.

```
import re
    your_string ="""PERSON_ID<|>DEPT_ID<|>DATE_JOINED
        AAAAA<|>S1<|>2021/01
    /03
        BBBBBB<|>S2<|>2021/02/03
        CCCCC<|>S1<|>2021/03/05"""
    print(re.sub(r'\s{1,}','',your_string.strip()))
```

After this step I get tape-like strings:

```
PERSON_ID<|>DEPT_ID<|>DATE_JOINEDAAAAA<|>S1<|>2021/01/03BBBBBB<|>S2<|>2021/02/03CCCCC<|>S1<|>2021/03/05
```

Now I need to feed in a correct next line in `"2021/01/03BBBBBB"`.
Assuming the total number of columns is 3, so we need to feed the next line between each:
the 2nd delimiter to 3rd delimiter,
the 4th delimiter to 5th delimiter,
the 6th delimiter to 7th delimiter...and so on.

Assuming the date shown in the string at a fixed length of 10, so I need a new line spacing feed in each designated delimiter after a string length of 10.

Assuming the data head will not change, so I can insert a new line spacing after a string length of 33 from the beginning of the file.

Then, finally, I can get my correct data in lines, the output of the rows in CSV would be like,

```
PERSON_ID<|>DEPT_ID<|>DATE_JOINED
AAAAA<|>S1<|>2021/01/03 
BBBBBB<|>S2<|>2021/02/03 
CCCCC<|>S1<|>2021/03/05
```

After this, I can separate them by the string delimiters. Hence, complete the mismatched lines restoration.

Therefore, I need help on how to insert a next line between the designated delimiters at a string length of 10 from its beginning?

Thanks!

Comment: don't repost https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69583374/restore-the-order-of-mismatched-lines-of-csv-file-in-python let your question be reopened

Comment: 1) Use the csv package; 2) Filter lines that have less that the three fields you are looking for; 3) lstrip the first field if you don't want the leading spaces.

Answer (score 0):

What about getting lines of fields directly? Like that:

```py
sep = '<|>'
your_data = [line.strip().split(sep) for line in your_string.strip().split('\n') if sep in line]
```

You got:

```
[['PERSON_ID', 'DEPT_ID', 'DATE_JOINED'], ['AAAAA', 'S1', '2021/01'], ['BBBBBB', 'S2', '2021/02/03'], ['CCCCC', 'S1', '2021/03/05']]
```

Comment: It helps a lot. Thank you!

Comment: with open('my_data.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    a_list_from_csv_file = your_data
    writer = csv.writer(out_fd, delimiter='|')
    for row in a_list_from_csv_file:
        writer.writerow(row)